# merge list of dictionaries into one dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I have this problem to solve. I have tried many ways. But cannot figure out the efficient way with minimum code.

```
my_list = [{'qwerty': 'hello'},
           {'asdfg': 'watermelon'},
           {'asdfg': 'banana'}]

merge_list_of_dicts(my_list)

returns the below list.

[{'qwerty': ['hello']},
 {'asdfg': ['watermelon','banana']}]
```

Comment: Please [edit] to show your attempt in `merge_list_of_dicts(my_list)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a dictionary of lists first then append the values from the original data.

It seems odd that you want a list of dictionaries instead of a single dictionary, so I provided both.

Try this code:

```
my_list = [{'qwerty': 'hello'},
           {'asdfg': 'watermelon'},
           {'asdfg': 'banana'}]

keys = set([list(i.keys())[0] for i in my_list])

dd = {k:[] for k in keys}

for d in my_list:
  dd[list(d.keys())[0]].append(list(d.values())[0])

print(dd)  # single dictionary

dd2 = [{x:dd[x]} for x in dd]

print(dd2)  # list of dictionaries
```

Output

```
{'qwerty': ['hello'], 'asdfg': ['watermelon', 'banana']}

[{'qwerty': ['hello']}, {'asdfg': ['watermelon', 'banana']}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't tell us what's inside the `merge_list_of_dicts()` but one way of implementing this would be:

```
from collections import defaultdict

my_list = [{'qwerty': 'hello'},
           {'asdfg': 'watermelon'},
           {'asdfg': 'banana'}]


def merge_list_of_dicts(list_of_dicts: list) -> list:
    merged = defaultdict(list)
    for d in list_of_dicts:
        for key, value in d.items():
            merged[key].append(value)
    return [{k: v} for k, v in merged.items()]


print(merge_list_of_dicts(my_list))
```

Outputs:

```
[{'qwerty': ['hello']}, {'asdfg': ['watermelon', 'banana']}]
```

Answer (score -1):

It would be better if you showed us the function you implemented. One straight-forward way to do it is to iterate over the list, then iterate over every dict and then add each dict value : key into a main dict.

```
mylist = [{"fruit" : "apple"}, {"drink" : "apple juice"}, {"meals" : ["apple pies", "apple salad"]}]
newdict = {}
for dictionary in mylist:
    for key in dictionary:
        newdict[key] = dictionary[key]

print(newdict)
```

Comment: This won't work for dicts with non-unique keys, as in the OP's question. Your code returns this `{'qwerty': 'hello', 'asdfg': 'banana'}` And your `mylist` is not `my_list` and its contents is different than OP's.

Comment: I didn't see that. He can use an if statement to see if there is already a value there and then put both those values into a list, or append if there already is one, but that would take about four more lines.